# Celery interval schedule doesn't executes on given interval

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

- I found that `IntervalSchedule` function of celery doesn't execute the tasks if the task interval is greater than 24 Hours.

The interval scheduler `django_celery_beat.models.IntervalSchedule`
 runs at a specifically given interval.

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule
    #should executes every 26 hours.
    >>> schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
    ...     every=26,
    ...     period=IntervalSchedule.HOURS,
    ... )
```

https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

- Now I'm creating a task to `print("Hello World!")` **with different `IntervalSchedule.HOURS`** Time Hours (5,10,14,23,27,32) Hours.
- I Noticed that this above `27,32` hour task never executes, whereas tasks which are under **`24 Hours i.e (5,10,14,23) of period gets executed every day`**

```
######## CELERY : CONFIG
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/Kolkata"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

- Versions :

```
celery (4.2.1)
django-celery (3.2.2)
django-celery-beat (1.3.0)
```

What are the possible reasons causing this & how do I debug to find the root cause?

Comment: Is this a question or you just telling everyone?

Comment: it's an question

Comment: Have you tried to check your hypothesis? E.g. a) create periodic (26 hours) task that writes to some file, b) create script that reads from this file, c) after read adjust time forward to 25 hours 59 minutes 55 seconds ?

Comment: celery-beat documentation has [warning](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#important-warning-about-time-zones) that TIME_ZONE change will not affect scheduled tasks. But it has no warning about adjusting the time on host. So it must be possible to test in a way I described above

Comment: I have updated the question with test cases.